# how to redirect a page using magento button?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I am new to magento, using html button I had create a record and redirect the pages also,
when I have create magento button I can't do any operations

what is the difference b/w html and magento buttons?
and how the perform action?

my code is:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('practice/index/new') ?>">
    <div class="mycustomstyle">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nom">First Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="prenom">Last Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nom">Telephone Number</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="mycustomstyle">
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create a New Record') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('practice/index/new');  ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create a New Record') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

see image:

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting of with the buttons. There is no technical difference between the buttons. It's only a styling matter. If you use the Magento button (and it's best to do so) you'll get a nicely styled button. Beyond that, both buttons do the same. The submit the form they're attached to.

How ever, make sure the `type` of the button is `submit` and not `button`.

Second, the redirect.
The redirect should be done in the controller and not in an onclick event of the button. The flow is roughly something like this.

`user fills out form and clicks button` > `controller handles the post data and saves it` > `controller redirects to desired end page`

Your controller would look something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_IndexController
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
      [...]
      // page that displays your form
      [...]
   }

   public function postoneAction()
   {
      [...]
      // code that handles the post data
      [...]

      // redirect back to the index page, or any other page of your controller
      $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
   }

   public function posttwoAction()
   {
      [...]
      // code that handles the post data differently
      [...]

      // redirect back to the index page, or any other page of your controller
      $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
   }
}
```

**[EDIT]** to have 2 different types of 'submit', take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953301/2x-submit-buttons-to-action-different-url) on Stackoverflow on swapping the `action` of the form depending on the button.

Basically you remove the `action` from the form, add a name to the form (`myform` for example`) and add it to the`onclick` of the buttons. Something like this.

```
<button onclick="document.myform.action='practice/index/postone';document.myform.submit();"> .... </button>

<button onclick="document.myform.action='practice/index/posttwo';document.myform.submit();"> .... </button>
```

Comment: hi sander, when I click it doesn't fire action  my function is in indexController.php                    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        $this->_redirect('practice/index/new');
    }
and phtml code is <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create a New Record') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('practice/index/new');  ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create a New Record') ?></span></span></button></p>

Comment: please remove the onclick event, maybe replace it with a form submit() event if you really want but that's not required. And make the `button` type submit`. Also make sure the `action` of the form directs to the controllers method that performs the saving of the data

Comment: ok if I have multiple buttons in one page then how can I give multiple urls? give a example?

Comment: It totally depends on what you want those buttons to do. But the form only performs one action on one URL per submit. You can't have it do both actions

Comment: ok for example: in magento save and save and continue edit 2 buttons is there both actions are different but 2 buttons are same page! there is working, but when I had create 2 buttons it's not working?

Comment: I think you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953301/2x-submit-buttons-to-action-different-url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10935/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-sander-mangel)